# How to change jsFiddle code so it will work in webrowser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this kind of questions has been asked, but I could not find answer to my problem.
So i have a working code in jsFiddle, which creates table, then you choose row and it colors that row to red. Everything is working fine in jsFiddle, in jsFiddle I have selected no - wrap `<body>`.

But when i try code from my editor (netbeans) it doesn't work. I have js code as separate file and jQuery library, added in head.

[My jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1mihcc/7okvbkg2/4/)

```
var sestevanje = 1;
var zdaj = new Date(); //nastavimo čas
var dan = ("0" + zdaj.getDate()).slice(-2);
var mesec = ("0" + (zdaj.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var datum = (dan) + "." + (mesec) + "." + zdaj.getFullYear();

function dodaj() {
   var opNaslov = $("#naslov").val();
   var vrNaslov = $("#vrsta").val();
   var nuOpravila = $("#nujnost").val();
   //var datum = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date());

   $("#vstavljanje").before("<tr id='nova'><td>" + sestevanje + "</td><td>" + opNaslov + "</td><td>"      + vrNaslov + "</td><td>" + nuOpravila + "</td><td>" + datum + "</td></tr>");

     sestevanje = sestevanje + 1;
   };
    $("table").delegate("tr", "click", function () {
       $(this).addClass("obarva");
    });

    $("#odstrani").click(function () {
       $(".obarva").hide();
    });
```

Comment: Put the `<script>` tag reference to this file right before the `</body>`

Answer (score 2):

> ...in jsFiddle i have selected no - wrap.

Specifically, you've chosen `No wrap - in <body>`.

> But when i try code from my editor (netbeans) it doesn't work. I have js code as separate file and jQuery library, **added in head.**

*(my emphasis)*

That's the problem — put them in the `body` instead, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

If you put scripts in the `head`, none of the DOM elements in the `body` exist as of when the script runs (because scripts are run when they're encountered*, before the elements have been encountered and created). But if you put the script at the end of the `body`, all of the elements exist because they've already been encountered and created. So you can find them, attach event handlers to them, etc.

If you **had** to put the scripts in `head`, you could use something like jQuery's [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) function (which waits to call your code until the DOM is "ready"), but that's really for situations where you aren't in control of where the script tag is placed.

---

* *"scripts are run when they're encountered"* — unless you use [`async` or `defer`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) and the browser supports them.

---

Barring specific reasons to do something else, the usual layout (recommended by the [YUI Best Practices](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) and by [Google's Closure library engineers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/closure-library-discuss/G-7Ltdavy0E/RjllWWJTXAcJ), amongst others) is to put CSS in the `head`, and scripts at the end of `body`, something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"><!-- Or whatever charset you use -->
<title>Your title</title>
<!-- `link` and/or `style` here for your CSS -->
<!-- other `head` content -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- body content -->
<!-- script tags -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"If you put scripts in the head (an anti-pattern, most of the time)"* why is that an anti-pattern? I was under the impression that it was actually better practice?

Comment: @mattytommo: For the very reason this question was asked: The elements the script wants to work with don't exist yet. I don't know how this "put scripts in the head" meme got started, but barring specific requirements to do that, it's just wrong. See the [YUI Best Practices](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html), which have been around for years, and which say (amongst other things) "CSS in head, scripts in body". It's not black-and-white, of course, sometimes you need to have scripts before content, but usually not.

Comment: Sorry to butt in here, but this is only an "anti-pattern" if your scripts aren't operating in what I would call a "responsible" way. Using modules, dependency management, event listeners, and watching for document ready (or the specific elements you need) will resolve this issue. Not only does it solve the issue of content not being ready, but it also promotes reusable, maintainable, future-proof code. The head is the right place for script tags, but they have to be written defensively.

Comment: @rockerest: Completely agree about using modules, dependency management, etc. That has nothing whatsoever to do with script placement. Disagree about 'ready' mechanisms; they're a solution to a problem that  putting scripts at the end of `</body>` doesn't have.

Comment: The anti-pattern comment seems to be distracting from the answer, I'll remove it.

Comment: The major reason for putting scripts at the end of a page is that [loading scripts can block](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html) other things from downloading. If you put the scripts at the end images and other assets can load in parallel before the scripts start blocking things. Most modern browsers will [load scripts in parallel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1915-how-javascript-loading-and-blocking-works-by-default.htm), but this still blocks other things from loading. Putting the scripts at the end helps to improve the perceived and actual page load speed.